# #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQL Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, syntax-error

I've looked over similar questions and see several similar questions with unclear answers, so figured I'd ask here.

```
'''
USE country_club;


SELECT fac.name,
       concat(mem.firstname, ' ', mem.surname) AS fullname,
       starttime =
  (SELECT starttime
   FROM Bookings
   WHERE starttime LIKE '2012-09-14%'),
       (slots * 30) AS mincost,
       CASE
           WHEN boo.memid=0 THEN boo.slots*fac.guestcost
           ELSE boo.slots*fac.membercost
       END AS cost
FROM Bookings AS boo
LEFT JOIN Members AS mem ON boo.memid = mem.memid
LEFT JOIN Facilities AS fac ON boo.facid = fac.facid
HAVING cost > 30;
'''
```

The error showed up after I added the second SELECT statement, and I know it's not the best way to query, but it's a requirement for my assignment.

Comment: The website is sql.springboard.com and I know it's phpMyAdmin 4.0.10deb1. If you want, I can run a SQL command to learn more.

Comment: How do you run this query? In phpmyadmin? Or do you have e.g. a php page that runs this? The error you get usually means that you sent a new query while the previous one was not completed yet (which e.g. includes that you have to fetch the complete resultset for the previous select, even if you maybe do not need it). If you use phpmyadmin or the mysql client, they will usually do this for you (apart from bugs maybe, which phpmyadmin has a few), but if you have your own script/app/..., this might be the problem, so you may need to add some details about it.

Comment: I run the query in phpmyadmin. I don't use a script. Is there a workaround to store the query data?

Comment: Consider contacting springboard about this error as this look like it is a PHPmyAdmin possible setting related error..  More or less related to [Buffered and Unbuffered queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) which can cause `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQL Subquery` errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the clause of SQL causing your trouble is this. (If that's not true please edit your question to clarify it.)

```
 WHERE ...
 starttime =
  (SELECT starttime
    FROM Bookings
    WHERE starttime LIKE '2012-09-14%'),
```

This is a strange operation. It looks like you want all the `starttime` values on a particular date. So why not just say that in your query? What you need is something like this.

```
 WHERE ...
        starttime  >= '2012-09-14 00:00:00'
   AND  starttime < '2012-09-14 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

I believe you're getting the oddball diagnostic "Commands out of sync" error because your query says

```
   SELECT WHERE .... value = (whole mess of values)
```

and your MySQL server chased its tail trying to understand you and eventually gave up rather than rejecting it as a syntax error straightaway.

Comment: USE country_club;
SELECT WHERE fac.name, concat(mem.firstname, ' ', mem.surname) as fullname,
 starttime =
  (SELECT starttime
    FROM Bookings
    WHERE starttime LIKE '2012-09-14%'), (slots * 30) as mincost,

Comment: I updated the query with the above, and came across an error.  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: The text in your comment isn't even close to valid SQL.  You may want to rework it.